# Get trending words as a stream with Tweepy

Tags: python, streaming, tweepy

**What I know:**

I have been using Tweepy for a long period and I know how you can create a stream to get new Tweets with a given keyword.

I also know that you can get trending keywords in a specific region from the documentation.

**What I am trying to achieve**:

I was wondering how I can use the trending APIs to get trending topic but in a form of a stream, so if a topic starts trending in a place, I will like a similar event to the `on_data` event on the stream listener to get fired and return the new trending topic.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Or any hint on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's API has no streaming endpoint for this, so you'll simply have to poll the [GET trends/place](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place) endpoint with [`API.trends_place`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.trends_place).

Comment: thank you for the answer, I knew about this one but I am looking for a better solution.